# Reformatting output of colMeans so it is two columns

Tags: r, format, output

I have a data frame where I created an additional 50 variables and I want to double check the data by taking the means of the first 10 rows and compare it to the means  of 10 rows in excel. The output is not easily pasted into excel as it is in rows and then with 50 variables it is just a row of variable names and then a row of numbers and then repeated for multiple lines.

I'd like to get the output into 2 columns, varname and then the mean. So I can just cut and paste in excel to make sure the numbers match the variables were created correctly.

```
fans <- data.frame(
  population = c(1234, 5678, 2345, 6789, 3456, 7890,
                4567, 8901, 5678, 9012, 6789),
  bears = c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567,678, 789, 890, 901, 135, 246),
  average = c(0.123, 0.234, 0.345, 0.456, 0.567, 0.678, 0.789, 0.890, 0.901, 
              0.135, 0.246),
  packersfa = c(11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100,122),
  vikingsf = c(39, 49, 59, 61, 32, 22, 31, 92, 52, 10, 122))

print(fans)

y<-colMeans(Filter(is.numeric,fans))
format(y, scientific = FALSE)

population          bears        average      packersfa       vikingsf 
"5667.1818182" " 487.6363636" "   0.4876364" "  65.1818182" "  51.7272727"
```

Keep in mind that the above line is actually a lot of lines with var on one line and the numbers on the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this simply by making the column means into a data.frame.

```
data.frame(colMeans(Filter(is.numeric,fans)))
population                       5667.1818182
bears                             487.6363636
average                             0.4876364
packersfa                          65.1818182
vikingsf                           51.7272727
```

Comment: Thanks. That was nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If we need two columns, use `stack` as `format`ted 'y' or without format, the `colMeans`  returns a named `vector`

```
stack(format(y, scientific = FALSE))[2:1]
#    ind       values
#1 population 5667.1818182
#2      bears  487.6363636
#3    average    0.4876364
#4  packersfa   65.1818182
#5   vikingsf   51.7272727
```

---

With `tibble`, `enframe` is another option

```
library(tibble)
format(y, scientific = FALSE) %>%
   enframe
```